# MSSQL Server on Ubuntu 20.04 python (>= 2.7.0) unmet dependencies

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, ubuntu

MSSQL server was installed and running fine on Ubuntu 19.10. However, after upgrading OS to 20.04 Beta, the linux upgrade process uninstalled MSSQL server and now facing unment dependency problem when I try to reinstall it, It seems required python package is available on the machine but not sure why the setup process is not taking.

What is going wrong here? Please help.

Followed steps as given here to install the MSSQL server (which worked fine on Ubuntu 19.10): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15

[image: MSSQLServer on Ubuntu 20.04 python unmet dependency]

Comment: Not going to get much help running on an unsupported and beta OS. 18.04 is the supported version - so your prior OS is also unsupported.

Comment: hmm...so let me wait for stable 20.04 then. In the meantime, I am able to setup MSSQL-Server on docker and managed to resume my development activities.

Comment: I'm sure you're aware that Python 2.x is now officially end-of-life and that the Ubuntu developers are working very hard to remove it from 20.04. For example, [With Python 2 EOL'ed, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Moves Along With Its Python 2 Removal](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Python-2-EOL-Ubuntu-20.04).

Comment: Yes, I am aware. Thanks for reconfirming. What made me wonder is that (if you see my screen shot), despite required python version being installed, apt failed to recognise it. I can see that it is more to do with Microsoft fixing this issue than linux distro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With latest ubuntu update (still in Beta though), MSSQL server is now able to install and run without any problems. Looks like Ubuntu fixed it.

[image]